# How to remove the regex match up to the first instance of a string (if it exists)?

Tags: regex

**Input:** (3 separate strings)

```
soft pastel
mixed media on paper
oil, sawdust on paper stretched on linen
```

I am trying to return the string prior to the first instance of " on"

I'm using: `(.*?)( on)` but this returns nothing for "soft pastel"

I've not been able to find a way to make " on" optional.
How do I include a regexmatch up to " on" only if " on" exists in the string?

https://regex101.com/r/LJxVtN/2

**Desired output**

```
soft pastel
mixed media
oil, sawdust
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes, first occurrence of text up to space + `on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/zNS1GP/2) is probably what you're looking for:

```
^(.*?)(?: on.*)?$
```

It uses both lazy quantifier `*?` and "optional" operator `?`, so you will also capture strings that don't include `on`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the settings you already set in the provided regex101 sandbox (multi-line and global), a `regex` that does the job is:

```
^(.*?)( on|$).*$
```

If you use `$1` as the replacement string, the outcome is the one you expect.

Check it on https://regex101.com/r/bzqkAz/1